# PYTHON: A "Gambling" program. Can't change value of a variable? (v. 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7

What I was trying do do was make "cash" like a balance. Therefore I want to be able to change that value. But when I run the program, the value of variable "cash" doesn't seem to change when I subtracted from it. The player is supposed to lose cash when they guess wrongly on the dice roll. More info is in the code itself. It would be much appreciated if answers have a brief explaination, im doing this to learn, its purely constructive.

```
    print ""
    import time
    cash = 5000
    print 'you brought','$',cash,'today'
    while cash>0:
        from random import randint
        die = randint(1,1)
        while True:
                try:
                    print
                    choice1 = int(raw_input('First guess: '))
                    print
                    choice2 = int(raw_input('Second guess: '))
                    print
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print 'Please, enter a number.'
        print 'rolling die..'
        time.sleep(3)
        if choice1+choice2==die:
            #PROBLEM: The operation below does not change the value of cash, why not?. 
                cash=cash+1000
                print cash
                print 'you rolled',die
                print 'win! you won $1000, you\'re new balance is:',cash
                #PROBLEM: The new val of cash should be printed here ^ but it remains as 5000
        else:
            cash-1000
            print 'you rolled',die
            print 'lose! you lost $1000, you\'re new balance is:',cash
        if cash<0:
            print 'Bankrupt.'
            time.sleep(3)
            quit()
        if cash==1000000:
            print 'Millionaire!'
            break
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cash-1000
```

Here you perform a subtraction, then throw the result away. What you want instead is:

```
cash = cash - 1000
```

Or just:

```
cash -= 1000
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is just a simple typo that the OP wanted us to debug for him rather than doing it himself, not that he doesn't understand how to assign to variables. If I've guessed wrong, then your answer explains it better than mhlester's…

Answer (score 1):

```
cash - 1000
```

should be

```
cash -= 1000
```

Otherwise you aren't assigning `cash - 1000` *to* anything; just evaluating it

Answer (score 0):

In line 28, where you typed `cash-1000`, you are not changing the cash variable. It should be `cash = cash - 1000` or simply `cash -= 1000`.
Other problems in your code:

1. Line 6: Don't import a module multiple times. This slows down the program.
2. Line 20: You are adding the two choices together, but I'm pretty sure you want to check both of them if they equal die. Do this by typing `if choice1 == die or choice2 == die:` instead. You expected `cash` to be printed by that line as you commented in line 26, but it never will because the if statement is flawed.